# When to make dua during prayer

Tags: salat, dua, sajda, tashahhud

Salam, i have just started praying and i am in the process of learning more about islam. While I know you can make dua during sujood, i was wondering if it is permissible to ask for worldly things like marriage/a specific person for marriage and whether it can be done in English.

The second part of my question is related to duas before and after tasleem. Some say it can be done before tasleem, others say it can be done after tasleem. What is the proper way to do it as I want to make sure I do not make a mistake.

(My questions relate to prayers done at home)

Thank you

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. Please check the site I strongly assume this question has an answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Salam, You can ask for worldly affairs in salah, but you cannot ask in a non-Arabic language. All saying must be in Arabic in salah. You are new Muslim and it could be hard for you to say in Arabic but try more.
It is better to recite dua after tasleem and it has more rewards. refer to [Al-Inshirah: [94:7]](https://quran.com/94)

Comment: Is this your opinion or do you have any proof for that.

Comment: Salam @Medi1Saif, I avoid giving my personal opinion on such issues. I checked Sunni and Shiite sources. The Sunnis do not consider it permissible (https://vaislamah.com/pgquestionanswer/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A8/) . I checked the opinion of Shia scholars (https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa27660). Opinions differ, but the majority opinion is that it should not be allowed.

Comment: This does not mention a difference of opinion and this answer is actually incorrect in general. Check out my answer here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/77518/51636